# IntelliJ IDEA one project - two operating systems

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I am creating a java project with a friend of mine, he is using windows and I am using ubuntu. I didn't give it much thought because java is cross-platform but I am having trouble opening the project I cloned from our git repo that he created in windows. The file browser recognizes the project but when I open the folder with the intelliJ icon it only opens the iml file and the class files, but not the folders and I don't have a hierarchy on the left tab. So I am wondering if it is a problem with our OS or if its some problem with intelliJ.

Comment: How your friend create the project? Do you have the same IntelliJ version of your friend? Sharing the .iml file is not a good choice, you should be able to import the project. Try this, copy the project in a new folder, remove the existing iml file and try to import the folder inside IntelliJ as a new project.

Comment: If you are going to share projects, its usually best practise not to sure the IDE project files, that way each participant can use their preferred IDE.  Try removing the project files from the git repo, and then each importing the code as a new project, and have a git ignore file set to ignore intellij project files.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the project up with Git? You should only be pushing your source files, and all others (such as the .iml) should be ignored. That way, any person using any OS or any IDE can easily set it up on their own.

Try removing all your files from git besides the source files. Now, if you clone it and set it up with IntelliJ, any IntelliJ specific files should stay locally, and only source files will be pushed.